# Getting second GPU monitors outputted as Multi-Display

Tags: graphics, display-settings, multi-monitor, amd

**OS**

Kali Linux 1.0.6

**Hardware**

HD7950 x 3

BenQ Monitors x4 - 1920x1080

Kogan Monitors x2 - 2560 x 1440

**Xorg.conf**

http://pastebin.com/JqTPUw7s

**Situation**

Currently I'm trying to get all 6 monitors running as a multi-display desktop. GPU1 is outputting the picture for Kogan monitors x 2 and BenQ monitors x 2 perfectly. The OS can see all AMD cards. The problem lies in the fact that when I try and get the two final monitors outputting from GPU2 the only selectable option for outputting is "Single Display Desktop", not multi-display desktop with the previous 4 working monitors.

Any help would be greatly appreciated with this configuration issue. Any questions please ask.

Comment: try this http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Configuring , and If I'm remembering this correctly, editing `xorg.conf` it's not a great pick on all modern distros .